# Integration Testing Services With Multiple Repositories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, nunit

Say I have a class `EmployeeService` that looks something like this:

```
public class EmployeeService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Employee> _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeService(IRepository<Employee> employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    ...

    // Relevant methods that deal with operations on employees.

...
```

The `_employeeRepository` has a `DbContext` and enables `CRUD` operations. The `DbContext` connects to a `MySQL` database.

My integration-test class is defined as:

```
[TestFixture]
public class EmployeeServiceTests
{
    // System under test.
    private EmployeeService _sut;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _sut = new EmployeeService(
                   new Repository<Employee,TestDatabaseContext>(
                       new TestDatabaseContext()));
    }

    ...

    // Tests.

...
```

The `TestDatabaseContext` is initialized with `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` and some seed data.

I have **two** questions (the second is linked with the first):

1. The database is *not* dropped in between tests. Why?
2. How do I isolate my integration tests? I have service classes that depend on other service classes which connect to seperate databases (`MySQL` & `MSSQL`).

Comment: why dont you mock your repository rather than using a test database?

Comment: As far as I am aware you're not *supposed* to mock in integration testing, because you are verifying how the components of your system interact. I believe the interaction with external dependencies (the database) is also important. Also, I have already mocked the repository in the unit tests.

Comment: true true. It just that you have EF problems. I would say its dosnt refresh the db because you are still in the same app domain between tests

Comment: as to isolation I have seen people recomend database snapshots. these allow you to create a copy of your DB with a unique name. might be MSSQL only though